# SQL Server Database Size Reduction Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 Express Database which is 7.8 GB in size

DataFile 1.2 GB
LogFile    6.6 GB

Recovery Model = Full
Auto Shrink = False

On a Live database, what is the best way to reduce the size of this database?

Comment: Read up on [Recovery Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) and that should help you understand why your database has grown so large. Unless you're just low on disk space, I would handle the log appropriately (regular tlog backups or change recovery model) but not shrink it unless it meets some [criteria](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx)

Comment: On a Live database, can I change the recovery model from FULL to Simple. I can set a Backup job that takes backup of the database everyday? What will happen to the log file when I switch from FULL to Simple?

Comment: Yes you can. The syntax would be `ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT` and you can use windows task scheduler to create a full backup on whatever schedule makes sense for your application. Database backup code `BACKUP DATABASE [MY_DATABASE] TO  DISK = N'C:\mydatabase.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'My Database backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10` **But, don't try any of this in production,** _yet_. The backup is fine, it won't hurt you. Before change anything production related, try them in a dev/test environment first and evaluate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can shrink a database running in full recovery model, you must backup the transaction log.  So the procedure is to run a transaction log backup, and then shrink the log file.

If you have never performed a transaction log backup then you will continue to suffer from run-away log files and shrinking it will only be a band-aid solution.

Comment: Steven, how can I do a transaction log back up? Also I have a limit of 10 GB which I will running out on very soon. So I probably won't need that transaction log which is 7.8 GB. Btw, is it normal to have log files that big. Does it effect performance?

Comment: From the Sql Management Studio UI, Right click your DB, choose Tasks -> Backup.  Set Backup Type to "Transaction Log".

Regarding if its normal to have a log that big, that ultimately depends on the DB, but in your case its surely due to a runaway transaction log, so no its not normal

Answer (score 1):

- You can also identify unused tables and remove those tables(if there is)
- you can create Archive database that will stored some old unused data
- you can normalize your database more to reduce table size.

hope this information helps you.